# How to have two different colors for two UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

Are there any standard methods for having two different colors for two `UIBarButtonItem`s on a `navigationBar` at the same time?

This could be achieve using custom `UIButton`, e.g.:

```
UIButton *confirmBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
confirmBtn.titleLabel.font =[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
[confirmBtn setTitle:@"Confirm" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
confirmBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -40);
[confirmBtn setTitleColor:[ColorSetter colorWithHexString:@"ffd420"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
confirmBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 50);
[confirmBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(DoneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *confirmBtnBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:confirmBtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = confirmBtnBarItem;
```

Comment: You could use image for two different UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Thanks Nitin, Need it for text button

Comment: Two button means left and right button.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, Yes, left and right button.